# Creating a new column based on a condition gives an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a dataframe like this :

```
           Patch  Last reward  First reward  Difference    Name  Block_No.
group_id                                                                 
1             3          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          1
2             4         43.0          54.0        11.0  XYZ          1
3             5          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          2
4             6         40.0          65.0        25.0  XYZ          2
5             7          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          3
6             0          0.0           0.0         0.0  XYZ          3
```

I want to create a  new column called 'Rep_rate' based on the following condition:
if block_no. = 1 then if patch = 3 , Rep_rate = 4 , else Rep_rate = 0.

I tried doing this :

```
if (df_last['Block_No.']) == 0:
            for i in range (len(df_last)):
                if df_last['Patch'][i] == 1: 
                    rep = 8
                else:
                    rep = 0
                df_last['Rep_Rate'] = rep

if (df_last['Block_No.']) == 1:
                for i in range (len(df_last)):
                    if df_last['Patch'][i] == 1: 
                        rep = 4
                    else:
                        rep = 0
                    df_last['Rep_Rate'] = rep

 if (df_last['Block_No.']) == 3:
                for i in range (len(df_last)):
                    if df_last['Patch'][i] == 1: 
                        rep = 8
                    else:
                        rep = 0                            
                    df_last['Rep_Rate'] = rep
```

However when i try this i get the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

try via boolean masking and loc accessor:

```
m=(df['Block_No.'].eq(1)) & (df['Patch'].eq(3))
df.loc[m,'Rep_Rate']=4
df.loc[~m,'Rep_Rate']=0
```

OR

via numpy's `where()` method:

```
#import numpy as np

m=(df['Block_No.'].eq(1)) & (df['Patch'].eq(3))
df['Rep_Rate']=np.where(m,4,0)
```

Comment: can i use this for multiple patches ? like df['patch'].eq(3,4,5) ? something like that?

Comment: if i use it for multiple patches it doesnt work.

Comment: @Kshtj then put your conditions in your question...then I will make changes in the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for x in df_last['Block_No.']
    if x == condition:
```

The error might be because you're comparing a series to a number,